# No package oracle-j2sdk1.7 available?

Tags: cloudera-manager

I am running following command for cloudera installation

```
 ./cloudera-manager-installer.bin
```

After accepting oracle license i getting error **installation failed for logs go to** ***2.install-oracle-j2sdk1.7.log***

following is contents of the log file

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, refresh-packagekit, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.syringanetworks.net
 * extras: mirror.sanctuaryhost.com
 * updates: centos.corenetworks.net
Setting up Install Process
No package oracle-j2sdk1.7 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

anyone has this type of error ? give suggestions ?

Answer (score 5):

On CentOS 6.4 I needed

```
yum clean all
rm -rf /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/cloudera-manager
```

It's the same as user2130332 wrote, but the path is more complicated. So the universal solution would be:

```
yum clean all
find /var/cache/yum -type d | grep cloudera- | xargs rm -rf
```

Comment: Can you explain why your answer solves the question?

Comment: The error is caused by files from previous installation and the uninstall script (/usr/share/cmf/uninstall-cloudera-manager.sh) does not the work. So we have to manually.

Comment: Good stuff... can you actually update your answer though? Moderators generally look at answer content that only has a couple lines like that and flag them for deletion. Adding the explanation you have int he comment will help!

Comment: I am getting similar error in SuSE. 'oracle-j2sdk1.7' not found. What needs to be done?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is on a RHEL type system, try this:

```
yum clean all
rm -rf /var/cache/yum/cloudera-*
```

I had the same problem and this solved it.

Comment: Ya thanks for the answer...the error is gone...these installation files of previous installations causes error.we need to remove it first..thanks

Comment: Why the negative ranking? :(

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work for some reasons you can always download proper rpm from cloudera archive, install it with `rpm -ivh` and push the installation further

`http://archive.cloudera.com/cm5/redhat/6/x86_64/cm/5/RPMS/x86_64/`