# No package oracle-j2sdk1.7 available while installing Cloudera manager in CentOS 7

Tags: hadoop, centos, cloudera, cloudera-cdh, cloudera-manager

I am running following command for cloudera installation

```
 ./cloudera-manager-installer.bin
```

After accepting oracle license i am getting the following error

> oracle-j2sdk1.7 installation failed.
>   See /var/log/cloudera-manager-installer/1.install-oracle-j2sdk1.7.log for details. 
>   Click OK to revert this installation.

When I log into the file `1.install-oracle-j2sdk1.7.log` by going into the folder using `cd /var/log/cloudera-manager-installer/` and view it using `vi 1.install-oracle-j2sdk1.7.log` , I see the following error

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.cogentco.com
 * extras: mirrors.advancedhosters.com
 * updates: mirror.umd.edu
No package oracle-j2sdk1.7 available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I tried every solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22090992/no-package-oracle-j2sdk1-7-available) and when I reinstall it, I am still getting the same error. When I tried

```
yum clean all
find /var/cache/yum -type d | grep cloudera- | xargs rm -rf
```

I am getting this message:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/cloudera-cdh5/gen/primary.xml’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/cloudera-cdh5/gen/primary.xml.sqlite’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/cloudera-cdh5/packages’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/cloudera-cdh5/cachecookie’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/cloudera-cdh5/primary.xml.gz’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/cloudera-cdh5/gen/primary.xml’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/cloudera-cdh5/gen/primary.xml.sqlite’: Permission denied
rm: cannot remove ‘/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/cloudera-cdh5/packages’: Permission denied
```

Can someone please help or give any suggestions?

Comment: `rm: cannot remove ‘/var/cache/yum/x86_64/7/cloudera-cdh5/gen/primary.xml’: Permission denied`

Can you try as sudo?

Comment: I tried with `sudo find /var/cache/yum -type d | grep cloudera- | xargs rm -rf` as well, but its showing the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get rid of this permission denied issue while deleting, you need to

`find /var/cache/yum -type d | grep cloudera- |sudo xargs rm -rf`